# Dynamic Workload Console memory leak causes the application to crash

Tags: dynamic, memory-leaks, workload-scheduler

With Dash 3121 CP3 in Dynamic Workload Console v9.3 fp3 memory leak causes the application to crash. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem add the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) Argument:

-`Xgc: classUnloadingKickoffThreshold=1000`

Note that to WebSphere Application Server, the JVM requires a restart for the argument to take effect.